# Can I use a "one fits all" polyfill collection without breaking new browsers?

Tags: javascript, web, openlayers, openlayers-3, polyfills

I am using [OpenLayers](https://openlayers.org/) in a project. To support users with older browsers, one must use Polyfills for `requestAnimationFrame`, `Element.prototype.classList`, and `URL`.

OpenLayers itself suggests to use the Polyfill.io service. This is shown in one of their [examples](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/simple.html).

This would require me to load an external URL (https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=requestAnimationFrame,Element.prototype.classList,URL) into the user's browsers. The service looks at the browser's user-agent and gives it a Polyfill if the browser is old, otherwise this file is just empty. Of course, running code hosted elsewhere is a security thread I do not want to be responsible for, so I would prefer to self-host.

The Polyfill.io service is [available for running locally](https://github.com/Financial-Times/polyfill-service#running-locally), but I'd have to run a server for that. I would prefer to not do this.

Instead, I'd like to serve a static JS file to everyone. My concerns are:

1. Is this possible? Can I serve the same polyfill to every old browser or do different old browsers need differnet polyfills?
2. Will this break the new browsers? How can I avoid this?
3. Will this be a huge file?

I appreciate your help very much.

Comment: I think this is an excellent question, but the scope is very wide and could lead to very opinionated answers. Nonetheless kuddos

Answer (score 1):

A generic answer, not tailored specifically to [polyfill.io](/questions/tagged/polyfill.io) or [openlayer](/questions/tagged/openlayer).

A good written polyfill should always start by checking if the method/object/function is available. If so, do nothing, if not add.

Usable in every old browser, well there you need to do some investigating yourself. Of course an old version of *Netscape Navigator* wouldn't be able to handle some or all of the polyfills because JavaScript is a living language. Generically you want to be able to serve everything from IE7 till Edge, Safari, Opera, Chrome and Firefox. And preferably the version that started to adhere to the W3C standards.

These versions contain all the standard JavaScript building blocks to write polyfills with. If a browsers is unable to mimic behaviour of more modern methods the polyfill should in my opinion fail silently and another solution should be found.

If the file is huge depends on the amount of polyfills you want to include. But generally it will range from a few kBs to a few hundred.

> **In conclusion**: A polyfill should never try to replace a function already present and - if written correctly - should be usable in any browser. If the polyfill can't be executed because of missing dependencies it should notify the programmer during debugging or better provide the necessary documentation.

---

*polyfill.io* says the following in their documentation:

> We test browser support with a test suite for each feature.  A browser is considered compliant only if it passes all the tests, so this is a reasonably comprehensive test rather than a naive feature-detect.  To view the test suite for a feature in the browser you're using right now, click the Tests link in the feature list.  The results below are generated using browsers hosted by [BrowserStack](https://www.browserstack.com).